# How to get Eclipse SWT Browser component running on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) with Webkit?

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk, swt

I use the SWT Browser control in my Eclipse RCP application. On Linux Ubuntu 10.10 this depends on the user having installed xulrunner-1.9.2. This works fine.

However, on Ubuntu 11.04 I find that it ships by default with xulrunner-2.0. The SWT Browser does not support this. See http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327696 and http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/process_bug.cgi

So rather than ask the user to install xulrunner-1.9.2 I want to get the SWT Browser to run with WebKitGTK as per the instructions on the SWT FAQ - http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserwebkitgtk

I cannot get this to work at all. How do I fulfil "WebKitGTK 1.2.0 or newer must be in the library load path"?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not on Ubuntu, but think that doesn't matter much.

1. Check the version of `libwebkit-1.0-2` (it should be >= 1.2.0)
2. Install this package if absent
3. Check that `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib/jni` is in `java.library.path`
4. If you use SWT 3.6, also check that appropriate webkit jni wrapper is installed (e.g. `libswt-webkit-gtk-3.6-jni` and `org.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK` system property is set to `True

**Edit:** To localize source of the problem create minimalistic project and show the output

```
package foo;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWTError;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class BrowserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK"));

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        try {
            Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
            browser.setSize(shell.getSize());
            browser.setUrl("google.com");
        } catch (SWTError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work on either Eclipse 3.6 or 3.7 even though I met all the conditions. I wonder if there's something different about using Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)

Comment: @Phillipus bet you've missed something, see edit. It may take some time for me to respond, however.

Comment: Hi, thanks once again. I added one line:

System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK", "true");

Output of java.library.path is:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib

Comment: Your snippet works on Eclipse 3.6 when I set everything up. The strange thing is it doesn't work for my RCP application that uses the Browser even when I set System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK", "true")

Comment: @Phillipus: there is a chance that you set this porperty too late; have you tried to set it form command-line (hint: `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=True`)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that at as well. Your snippet works perfectly. Unfortunately it's not working with my Eclipse RCP application. There's something strange going on here either with Eclipse or Natty Narwhal. I shall try another Linux distro and compare.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 10.10. Everything is fine. It seems then that there are issues somewhere on 11.04 (Natty Narwhal). Many thanks for your help, barti_ddu.

Answer (score 16):

For Eclipse Juno SR1 (4.2 SR1) running on Ubuntu 12.04, the following worked for me:

1. Install the libwebkit package:  `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0`
2. Install the libwebkit jni wrapper:  `sudo apt-get install libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni`
3. Set the DefaultType and UseWebKitGTK properties (I did it by adding the following to my eclipse.ini file):

   ```
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
   ```

Comment: This helped me in Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Kepler 4.3, I was seeing HTML code in the Code Assistance.

Comment: on 16.04LTS with Eclipse Neon, installing `libwebkitgtk-3.0-0` was enough.

Answer (score 5):

Simply installing the "hotot" (Twitter) App via Software Center, which drags WebKit along, did the trick for me. - A "sudo apt-get install -y libwebkitgtk-1.0-0", or build from source as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit, would probably work as well.

Comment: This worked for me (Ubuntu 13.10 and Eclipse Kepler)

Comment: downvote for suggesting to install a totally unrelated app just because of its dependencies

Answer (score 0):

For Natty, check out this page: http://www.maplef.net/blog/archives/ubuntu-upgrade-eclipse3-5-to-3-6.html (ignore japanses/chinese stuff, just follow the code to reach shangri-la)