# Eclipse (ZIP distro) SWT link error

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Eclipse seems to be unable to start an embedded browser.

The anwser in [Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries) won't help, as I don't even have a /usr/lib/jni folder.

I have a Eclipse 4.3 installed from a standalone ZIP file. 
It's running on a Oracle Java 1.6.0_39 installed via the standalone (.bin) installer.
The system is Kubuntu 10.04.

Also sudo find /usr/lib/ -name "swt*" returns no results.

I guess I'm probbably missing some swt libraries, but I'm not sure which.

Here is the eclipse error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/usr/lib/mozilla'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/jbochenski/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/664/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4333.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/jbochenski/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4333.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/jbochenski/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so
)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:2024)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:701)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.ui.libprov.user.internal.DownloadLibraryWizardLicensePage.createControl(DownloadLibraryWizardLicensePage.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.ui.libprov.user.internal.DownloadLibraryWizard.open(DownloadLibraryWizard.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.ui.libprov.user.UserLibraryProviderInstallPanel$4.widgetSelected(UserLibraryProviderInstallPanel.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage.handleFurtherConfigHyperlinkEvent(FacetsPropertyPage.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage.access$5(FacetsPropertyPage.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$7.linkActivated(FacetsPropertyPage.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.access$2(AbstractHyperlink.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink$4.handleEvent(AbstractHyperlink.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/jbochenski/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/664/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4333.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/jbochenski/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4333.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/jbochenski/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:2009)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: It is `libxpcom.so` that can't be found, I think this is part of Mozilla XULRunner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it run by installing libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 - as suggested in [Open eclipse juno with error "No more handles ..." in Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125044/open-eclipse-juno-with-error-no-more-handles-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)