# Eclipse PDT: how to tune content assist proposals?

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt, content-assist

If I start writing my PHP code in editor I see proposals from picture #1 - unsorted methods contains a half-written expression (inconvenient)

[image: relevant but unsorted proposals]

If I write the same expression and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> I see expected proposals from picture #2 - methods sorted by the expression beginning (convenient)

[image: relevant and sorted proposals]

How to ensure that when entering an expression, the list of proposals corresponds to picture #2? Coding will go faster if I do not need to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> combination

Is there any Eclipse setting to fix it or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't webkit installed on your linux. See for example this article how to do it: [How to get Eclipse SWT Browser component running on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) with Webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817263/how-to-get-eclipse-swt-browser-component-running-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal)

Note since upcoming (Photon 4.8) release, webkit 2 will be default.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. It helped, I still used gtk2. Moved to gtk3

I use two IDE - PDT and RCP. In RCP SWT and GTK3 have bugs, therefore I use GTK2. And somehow this RCP config settings was copied to PDT